# Proper translation for "no border for this bird"?

Tags: traducción, méxico, animales

I have been finding different translations for this sentence I want to use.

> **No borders (plural) for this bird**
>   Hay fronteras papa esta ave.

I read "ave" is used for the general expression of all birds, nothing specific, whereas "pájaro" expresses a zoological distinguishment.

And, I also read that "pájaro" could have a homosexual implication.

> **No border (singular) for this bird**
>   Sin frontera para este pájaro
>   Ninguna frontera para este pájaro

I do have a particular bird in mind and it is from Mexico, so I wish to get the correct translation.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Why is your first example mistranslated? "Hay fronteras para esta ave" means "there are borderd for this bird"...

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed to translate that sentence. It could be "[there are] no borders...", then it is "no hay fronteras...", but it could also be understood as an order: "no borders for this bird!", then the translation could be "¡nada de fronteras para este pájaro!".

Comment: I agree that some more context is required. Are you speaking about a migrating bird that can move and live in different areas or countries without restrictions? Or is it metaphorical?

Comment: That first example is what a translation web site gave me. Yes, it is a migrating bird from Mexico. I am referring to a bird that was sighted in my area that is not a native, but a migrant from Mexico. What I wish to infer is that this bird doesn't care about borders and can fly over them and/or that this bird is against borders. And, I am hinting a metaphor.

Comment: Presumably you want to avoid the technical term _ave migratoria_  http://dle.rae.es/?id=4X8WU1M for some reason?

Comment: The term is not needed.  Anyone who knows this bird, knows that  it is migratory

Answer (score 1):

How about these?

- Es un ave sin fronteras.
- Es un ave que no tiene / no conoce fronteras.
- No existen fronteras para esta ave.

If used in a metaphorical sense, it could refer to a free soul or spirit (un ser libre, sin ataduras).

Comment: Gustavson, I like the third one. No existen fronteras para esta ave.

Comment: Yes, "existen" is always more sophisticated than "hay".

Comment: I had another paragraph attached to my reply, but it seems to have not posted. What I am doing is making a statement, not only about the bird, which is migratory, but a political statement about borders. It is serendipitous that, in this time,  a black-backed oriole, which is a migratory bird, rarely seen in the US, has landed here nearby where I live. The idea came to me in sort of a dream and I am creating a design. I like that "existen" is more sophisticated than ""hay", and am wondering if I can eliminate "existen" and just say " No fronteras para esta ave." Has more puch, more direct?

Comment: I'd say: "Sin fronteras para esta ave". "No fronteras" is not Spanish usage.

Comment: When I saw this one my immediate thought was that I would have said "This bird knows no boundaries" which has a nice symmetry with the two b sounds and the two n sounds. That brought me to _esta ave no reconece ninguna frontera_ which seemed to me in the spirit of your second suggestion  but stronger. Perhaps _reconecer_ is wrong here though.

Comment: @mdewey *reconocer* would be fine too, but slightly different, meaning not accepting an external imposition. *conocer* merely means being aware of the existence of such frontiers, in this case.

Comment: @retts I've been thinking that if we want to give the phrase the tone of a political protest, we could say something like: "Nada de fronteras para esta ave."

Comment: Gustavson, I like the last post. Yes, I am all for a hint of political protest tone. I went with the phrase "Sin fronteras para esta ave" for a few designs. I am also going to do a design using the word "wall" in place of border. Thank you for your interest and help.

Comment: @retts Happy to have been of help. Please note that "Nada de fronteras/Nada de muros para esta ave" has an imperative force that "Sin..." lacks.